# Calling " getContentResolver " in an Android Java class

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-contentresolver, android-context

I have an Service S which contains a Thread T. I also have a Java Class C. I would like to call a method of the class C from the thread T. The method is supposed to contain the lines :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
Cursor cursor1 =  getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null, null);
```

The problem is that I get the error " 
Cannot resolve the methode 'getContentResolver()' ".
I know this is a matter of Context, but I don't know how to solve it.

EDIT

Without considering the thread T, tried this :

The class C :

```
public class SMS {

private ArrayList<String> smsList = new ArrayList<>();

public SMS(Context context){        

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    Cursor cursor1 =  context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null, null);

    }
}
```

The service S :

```
public class MyService extends Service{

    SMS sms = new SMS(this);
}
```

But I get the error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.maxime.servicesms2.SMS.<init>(SMS.java:18)
```

Line 18 being :

```
Cursor cursor1 =  context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null, null);
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can make your service as a child of android.app.Service

```
public class ServiceS extends Service {...}
```

then it will have getContentResolver() method

Comment: My service has a getContentResolver() method, the problem is that the Class C does not have one apparently.

Comment: Then just make a class C inner (inside S) or make a reference to S in the C and inject it when instantiating C via constructor

Answer (score 0):

You should pass Context into the method in class C

Something like:

```
public void doSomething(Context context) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    Cursor cursor =  context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null, null);
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried to do this, but then when I'm in the thread T of the Service S, calling "  
    C.method(this); 
" prompts an error. I think the problem is that it's in a thread and not directly in the service.